# Reading Excel (.xlsx) file in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-excel

I am trying to read a .xlsx file from local path in PySpark.

I've written the below code:

```
from pyspark.shell import sqlContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
      .master('local') \
      .appName('Planning') \
      .enableHiveSupport() \
      .config('spark.executor.memory', '2g') \
      .getOrCreate()

df = sqlContext.read("C:\P_DATA\tyco_93_A.xlsx").show()
```

Error:

> TypeError: 'DataFrameReader' object is not callable

Comment: Hi @OMG, read allows you to access a DataFrameReader, which enables loading parquet / csv / json / text / excel / ... files with specific methods

Comment: @baitmbarek: shall i use .load.... please help

Comment: You can take a look at these suggestions first : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22736/is-there-any-way-to-read-xlsx-file-in-pysparkalso-want-to-read-strings-of-colum

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use pandas to read .xlsx file and then convert that to spark dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()

pdf = pandas.read_excel('excelfile.xlsx', sheet_name='sheetname', inferSchema='true')
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

df.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, but getting error like : ImportError: Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support

Comment: xlrd package is not installed. Just pip install xlrd, it will start working.

Comment: inferSchema is not (or no longer, probably?) a supported argument. (`TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inferSchema'`)

Comment: Is there a way to reading an Excel file direct to Spark without using pandas as an intermediate step?

Answer (score 1):

You could use crealytics package.

Need to add it to spark, either by maven co-ordinates or while starting the spark shell as below.

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell --packages com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.1
```

For databricks users- need to add it as a library by navigating
Cluster - 'clusterName' - Libraries - Install New - Provide 'com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.1' under maven coordinates.

```
df = spark.read
     .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
     .option("dataAddress", "'Sheet1'!")
     .option("header", "true")
     .option("inferSchema", "true")
     .load("C:\P_DATA\tyco_93_A.xlsx")
```

More options are available in below github page.

https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel

Comment: Version 0.14.0 was released in Aug 2021 and it's working. Version 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0 is also release for spark 3, but these are not working, so stick with 0.14.0