# Pyspark: Read csv file with multiple sheets

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

The **.csv** file I am using will have **multiple sheets** (Dynamic sheet names).

I have to create **dataFrames** for all the sheets

The syntax I am using:

```
df = self.spark.read
         .option("sheetName", None)
         .option('header', 'true')
         .csv(file_path)

sheet_names = df.keys()
print(sheet_names)
```

Error:

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading Excel (.xlsx) file in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59854917/reading-excel-xlsx-file-in-pyspark)

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615196/is-csv-with-multi-tabs-sheet-possible

Comment: @notNull I don't know the sheet names. If I can hardcode then no prob

Comment: @SarahMesser I need to use apache spark. The answer is in c#. I can solve it in any other languages, c#, python etc. I need to use `pyspark`

Comment: @AdritaSharma The question & answers I linked are only nominally about C#.  (There's no code in either the Q or A.) My point with the link is that "multisheet CSV" seems to be a mislabelling of multisheet Excel files, and that you may have better luck with the processing if you explicitly convert a multisheet XLSX to multiple CSVs before trying to ingest the data into PySpark.  Alternately look into PySpark direct handling of XLSX, if that's indeed your original format.

Comment: @SarahMesser I already have csv, I an do the same using pandas dataframe, trying to do the same using pyspark

Comment: @AdritaSharma A CSV has no sheet. It's just a plain text file where the delimtier between columns is supposed to be a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a CSV file, which is a plain text file, so first of all, trying to get excel sheet names from it does not make sense.

Second, [reading the CSV file](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv.html) returns you are [spark dataframe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame). This dataframe, as you can see in this documentation, has no method named "keys".